# Why was past simple preferred to past perfect in this context

Tags: past-tense

Here is another example from the NYT (March 17, 2020),

"Noah Diaz was in the middle of rewrites for his play “Richard & Jane & Dick & Sally” when the theater company The Playwrights Realm canceled the show’s New York run. Set to open April 3, it would have been Mr. Diaz’s Off Broadway debut.

From New Haven, where he is an M.F.A. candidate at the Yale School of Drama, Mr. Diaz, 26, said he had anticipated the news. The day before, he had watched in surprise as Yale Repertory Theater **scrapped** the final two shows in its season because of the pandemic — an action that came Wednesday, before the cascade of shutdowns that followed the closure of Broadway on Thursday.

Why is it not "had scrapped" as the event happened before  the cancellation of his first play.
I think it is because past perfect is already used and that the most important verb here is watch, the one that mattered

Comment: Past Perfect would be stylistically disastrous in the cited context. We don't normally repeat Perfect verb forms any more than we have to, but in this *specific* context it's not really even an option. Because ***as** [they scrapped them]* happened ***at the same time*** as the watching in surprise (which represents the *already* contextually established "past within the past" explicitly referenced by ***The day before***. English is good at recursion, but we *really* don't need 3 levels of Past times to be identified by different verb forms!

Comment: Note that *The day before, Yale Repertory Theater **had** scrapped the final two shows* would be fine. That's just ***Past*** and ***Past within the Past***. There's no need for ***Past within the Past within the Past***.